# Possible to create an AudioBuffer from memory ie an Int8Array

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio, web-audio-api

Is there a way to add raw data from memory as a sample to the Web Audio Api? I would like to add a Int8Array (or Int16Array) as a buffer, the buffer just have the samples and no format as WAV or MP3. I have tried the audioContext.createBuffer and such without succes.

Something like this:

```
var buffer = audioContext.createBuffer(1,8192, 22000);
var intArray = new Int8Array(....);
// -- fill intarray
buffer.buffer = intArray;
...
var source = context.createBufferSource();
source.buffer = buffer;
source.connect(context.destination);
```

If that is not possible is there a sound format compatible with contetx.decodeAudio() which is easy to "emulate" in memory? Ie just a header or something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is neither very intuitive, nor explicitly documented in the specs and also not really easy to find on the net:

but, you can simply modify the `Float32Array` which is returned by `getChannelData(<idx of channel>)` on any buffer.

don't forget to scale your samples to the range [-1, 1]

for your example you would scale and copy the values in the intArray to the floatArray obtained by calling:

```
floatArray = buffer.getChannelData(0)
```

Comment: Well, it IS documented that getChannelData returns a Float32Array.  :) But yes, that's exactly the way to do it.

Comment: @cwilso, yes, but the name seems to imply that it is read-only.

Comment: Wow! Thank you for the fast answare! And it worked!

 I haven't figured out the best way to solve it due to that the Float32Array is fixed sized and there doesn't seems to be a way to reinit the array with a new size. 

 I don't know if there is another way but as now I have to load an empty wav file as a source which is larger than any of my memory samples and then insert the samples into that.

 Maybe I need a empty buffer for all the samples. 

 I'm at least moving along, thank you!

Comment: @Perty, if I have understand you right:  
instead of re-sizing just create a new empty buffer of the desired size like you do in the beginning.

Comment: @kr1 Ahhrg! Thank you! I have tried to create empty buffers but just got an exception so I thought I made something wrong. When I read the api a little more I tried with a better value, ie 22050. Before I just tried 22000 and didn't expect it to be so picky about the sample rate.  


`context.createBuffer(1, 80000, 22050); // works
context.createBuffer(1, 80000, 22000); // don't work!
`
  
_The sampleRate parameter describes the sample-rate of the linear PCM audio data in the buffer in sample-frames per second. An implementation must support sample-rates in at least the range 22050 to 96000._