# Cut and Paste audio using web audio api and wavesurfer.js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, html, audio, web-audio-api

I am currently trying to make a web editor allowing users to easily adjust basic settings to their audio files, as a plugin I've integrated wavesurfer.js as it has a very neat and cross-browser solution for it's waveform.

After indexing a must-have list for the functionalities I've decided that the cut and paste are essential for making this product work, however after spending hours of trying to figure out how to implement this in the existing library and even starting to rebuild the wavesurfer.js functionalities from scratch to understand the logic I have yet to succeed.

My question would be if anyone can give me some pointers on how to start building a cut and paste functionality or maybe even an example that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

wavesurfer plugin:
http://wavesurfer-js.org

plucked web editor
http://plucked.de

EDIT Solution (instance is the wavesurfer object.):

```
function cut(instance){
  var selection = instance.getSelection();
  if(selection){
    var original_buffer = instance.backend.buffer;
    var new_buffer      = instance.backend.ac.createBuffer(original_buffer.numberOfChannels, original_buffer.length, original_buffer.sampleRate);

    var first_list_index        = (selection.startPosition * original_buffer.sampleRate);
    var second_list_index       = (selection.endPosition * original_buffer.sampleRate);
    var second_list_mem_alloc   = (original_buffer.length - (selection.endPosition * original_buffer.sampleRate));

    var new_list        = new Float32Array( parseInt( first_list_index ));
    var second_list     = new Float32Array( parseInt( second_list_mem_alloc ));
    var combined        = new Float32Array( original_buffer.length );

    original_buffer.copyFromChannel(new_list, 0);
    original_buffer.copyFromChannel(second_list, 0, second_list_index)

    combined.set(new_list)
    combined.set(second_list, first_list_index)

    new_buffer.copyToChannel(combined, 0);

    instance.loadDecodedBuffer(new_buffer);
  }else{
    console.log('did not find selection')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Reading this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14843695/352796) suggests you can create an empty AudioBuffer of the size of the audio segment you want to copy (size = length in seconds ⨉ sample rate), then fill its channel data with the data from the segment.

So the code *might be* like this:

```
var originalBuffer = wavesurfer.backend.buffer;
var emptySegment = wavesurfer.backend.ac.createBuffer(
    originalBuffer.numberOfChannels,
    segmentDuration * originalBuffer.sampleRate,
    originalBuffer.sampleRate
);
for (var i = 0; i < originalBuffer.numberOfChannels; i++) {
    var chanData = originalBuffer.getChannelData(i);
    var segmentChanData = emptySegment.getChannelData(i);
    for (var j = 0, len = chanData.length; j < len; j++) {
        segmentChanData[j] = chanData[j];
    }
}

emptySegment; // Here you go!
              // Not empty anymore, contains a copy of the segment!
```

Comment: Many thanks katspaugh! this is great! is there also a way to redraw the waveform when I paste the new segment to the original buffer.

Comment: @dennis, yes, there's `wavesurfer.loadDecodedBuffer` method, it takes an AudioBuffer. See https://github.com/katspaugh/wavesurfer.js/blob/a8772b8b5148c58c231d4ad7c1d8b62f37409efb/src/wavesurfer.js#L514

Answer (score 5):

Interesting question. First word that comes to mind is [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/). I can't talk from experience but if I was trying to achieve this I would approach it like:

*Let's assume you select a region of your audio track and you want to copy it and make a new track out of it (later maybe just appending it to an existing track).*

1. Use the `getSelection()` method provided by the nice *wavesurfer.js* library. This will give you `startPosition()` and `endPosition()`[in seconds].
2. Given those points you now can use **ffmpeg** on the backend to select the region and save it as a new file (eventually upload it to S3,etc.). See this [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/525210/splitting-an-audio-file-into-chunks-of-a-specified-length) to get an idea of how to call **ffmpeg** from your ruby app (the commandline parameters shown there can be helpful too).

Note that if you plan to copy and paste many regions to piece up a new track, making this in the backend all the time will probably make no sense, and I guess I'd try to look for a client-side JS approach.

I hope this is helpful at least for an easy use case, and gets you started for the rest ;)

**Update**
This might be worth reading.

- `Web Audio API`, tutorial [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/).
- HTML5 audio - State of play. [here](http://html5doctor.com/html5-audio-the-state-of-play/)(don't miss the section on TimeRanges, looks like a reasonable option to try).
- This [one](http://blog.humphd.org/vocamus-1092/?p=1092)(Outdated, but worth a look, interesting links).

Comment: Hi vint-i-vuit, thank you very much for your input. I now have a direction of how I can set this up, I am going for the client-side approach as the backend approach will probably be too heavy. On success I will make sure to return the favor and post my solution.

Comment: @dennis: I'm glad to hear that you now have a bit more of an overview of the challenge :) Also, have another look at my updated answer, I added some links that could help you get started on you JS-based approach.

Comment: Many many many thanks! Indeed the TimeRanges article seems very promising, I am currently working on a Javascript lib to cover these functionalities combined with the waveform of wavesurferjs it will be hosted on github as soon as it's in beta.