# How can i copy the audio data from a wavesurfer region into a new audio buffer?

Tags: node.js, audio, web-audio-api

Wavesurfer.js is great, but a little bit confusing.

I have wavesurfer implemented, but ***i want to build a way of cutting out the audio region the user selects and pasting it into a new audio buffer***. At present, i'm console logging in the regions js file to try and get the start and end times but getting very confused.

This is the waveform, i've clicked and dragged to create the region. I want to be able to run a function that copies this section into a new audio buffer. 
[image]

I've console logged here in the regions JS. [image]

Which outputs this to the console. [image]

HOWEVER. When i print region.start or region.end to the console, it's constantly 0 and 0.0800.... which you can see in the preview to the log, however once you expand to see more the actual region start and end are present. I have no idea why this is.

This link explains copying and pasting the whole file.
[Cut and Paste audio using web audio api and wavesurfer.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551854/cut-and-paste-audio-using-web-audio-api-and-wavesurfer-js)

any clues? I assume i need to get the figures for the start and end, then either use ffmpeg to chop it out, or if there is a way that i can do it myself via the Web Audio API and Wavesurfer itself that would be best.

Thanks

Comment: It would be more useful to provide your code as text, rather than an image.

Answer (score 1):

I know nothing about wavesurfer, but I can guess at the issue based on your confusion at seeing different values when logging the object or it's values.

`console.dir()` is similar to `console.log()`, and we can use it to more easily explore the problem.

Try this in the console:

```
var o = { n: 42 };
console.dir(o);
// -> now expand the logged object, you should see that n is 42
o.n = 43;
// notice that the previously logged object still states that n is 42
```

and contrast it to this session in the console:

```
var o = { n: 42 };
console.dir(o);
// don't expand the logged object just yet...
o.n = 84;
// -> now expand the logged object, you should see that n is 84
o.n = 43;
// notice that the previously logged object still states that n is 84
```

From this, it can be seen that Chrome captures the values of the dictionary/object at the point of the logged object first being expanded, not before.

I'm guessing, based on your report, that the region object is mutable, and that the values within it continue to change after the logging statements.

When you `console.log(region.end)` you are capturing the value "end" immediately, whereas when you `console.log(region)`...time-elapses...expand the values you see are captured at that point of expanding the object.

Perhaps you need to take a closer look at the API for wavesurfer. As a terrible hack you could just capture the values in a deferred way (using a timeout or something equally horrible), but I'd guess there must be a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented cut, copy, paste functionality based on wavesurfer. cut, copy are the functions which return you the region that you wanted to cut or copy. While paste function returns you the newly formed audioBuffer.

```
 export function paste(instance,cutSelection){
    var offlineAudioContext = instance.backend.ac
    var originalAudioBuffer = instance.backend.buffer;

    let cursorPosition = instance.getCurrentTime()
    var newAudioBuffer = offlineAudioContext.createBuffer(
        originalAudioBuffer.numberOfChannels,
        originalAudioBuffer.length + cutSelection.length,
        originalAudioBuffer.sampleRate);

    for (var channel = 0; channel < originalAudioBuffer.numberOfChannels;channel++) {

        var new_channel_data = newAudioBuffer.getChannelData(channel);
        var empty_segment_data = cutSelection.getChannelData(channel);
        var original_channel_data = originalAudioBuffer.getChannelData(channel);

        var before_data = original_channel_data.subarray(0, cursorPosition * originalAudioBuffer.sampleRate);
        var mid_data = empty_segment_data
        var after_data = original_channel_data.subarray(Math.floor(cursorPosition * originalAudioBuffer.sampleRate), (originalAudioBuffer.length * originalAudioBuffer.sampleRate));


        new_channel_data.set(before_data);
        new_channel_data.set(mid_data,(cursorPosition * newAudioBuffer.sampleRate));
        new_channel_data.set(after_data,(cursorPosition + cutSelection.duration)* newAudioBuffer.sampleRate);
    }
    return newAudioBuffer
}

export function cut(params,instance){
    /*
    ---------------------------------------------
    The function will take the buffer used to create the waveform and will
    create
    a new blob with the selected area from the original blob using the
    offlineAudioContext
    */

    // var self = this;
    var start = params.start;
    var end = params.end;

    var originalAudioBuffer = instance.backend.buffer;

    var lengthInSamples = Math.floor( (end - start) * originalAudioBuffer.sampleRate );
    if (! window.OfflineAudioContext) {
        if (! window.webkitOfflineAudioContext) {
            // $('#output').append('failed : no audiocontext found, change browser');
            alert('webkit context not found')
        }
        window.OfflineAudioContext = window.webkitOfflineAudioContext;
    }
    // var offlineAudioContext = new OfflineAudioContext(1, 2,originalAudioBuffer.sampleRate );
    var offlineAudioContext = instance.backend.ac

    var emptySegment = offlineAudioContext.createBuffer(
        originalAudioBuffer.numberOfChannels,
        lengthInSamples,
        originalAudioBuffer.sampleRate );

    var newAudioBuffer = offlineAudioContext.createBuffer(
        originalAudioBuffer.numberOfChannels,
        (start === 0 ? (originalAudioBuffer.length - emptySegment.length) :originalAudioBuffer.length),
        originalAudioBuffer.sampleRate);

    for (var channel = 0; channel < originalAudioBuffer.numberOfChannels;channel++) {

        var new_channel_data = newAudioBuffer.getChannelData(channel);
        var empty_segment_data = emptySegment.getChannelData(channel);
        var original_channel_data = originalAudioBuffer.getChannelData(channel);

        var before_data = original_channel_data.subarray(0, start * originalAudioBuffer.sampleRate);
        var mid_data = original_channel_data.subarray( start * originalAudioBuffer.sampleRate, end * originalAudioBuffer.sampleRate);
        var after_data = original_channel_data.subarray(Math.floor(end * originalAudioBuffer.sampleRate), (originalAudioBuffer.length * originalAudioBuffer.sampleRate));

        empty_segment_data.set(mid_data);
        if(start > 0){
            new_channel_data.set(before_data);
            new_channel_data.set(after_data,(start * newAudioBuffer.sampleRate));
        } else {
            new_channel_data.set(after_data);
        }
    }
    return {
        newAudioBuffer,
        cutSelection:emptySegment
    }

}

export function copy(region, instance){
    var segmentDuration = region.end - region.start

    var originalBuffer = instance.backend.buffer;
    var emptySegment = instance.backend.ac.createBuffer(
        originalBuffer.numberOfChannels,
        segmentDuration * originalBuffer.sampleRate,
        originalBuffer.sampleRate
    );
    for (var i = 0; i < originalBuffer.numberOfChannels; i++) {
        var chanData = originalBuffer.getChannelData(i);
        var emptySegmentData = emptySegment.getChannelData(i);
        var mid_data = chanData.subarray( region.start * originalBuffer.sampleRate, region.end * originalBuffer.sampleRate);
        emptySegmentData.set(mid_data);
    }

    return emptySegment
}

export function bufferToWave(abuffer, offset, len) {

    var numOfChan = abuffer.numberOfChannels,
        length = len * numOfChan * 2 + 44,
        buffer = new ArrayBuffer(length),
        view = new DataView(buffer),
        channels = [], i, sample,
        pos = 0;

    // write WAVE header
    setUint32(0x46464952);                         // "RIFF"
    setUint32(length - 8);                         // file length - 8
    setUint32(0x45564157);                         // "WAVE"

    setUint32(0x20746d66);                         // "fmt " chunk
    setUint32(16);                                 // length = 16
    setUint16(1);                                  // PCM (uncompressed)
    setUint16(numOfChan);
    setUint32(abuffer.sampleRate);
    setUint32(abuffer.sampleRate * 2 * numOfChan); // avg. bytes/sec
    setUint16(numOfChan * 2);                      // block-align
    setUint16(16);                                 // 16-bit (hardcoded in this demo)

    setUint32(0x61746164);                         // "data" - chunk
    setUint32(length - pos - 4);                   // chunk length

    // write interleaved data
    for(i = 0; i < abuffer.numberOfChannels; i++)
        channels.push(abuffer.getChannelData(i));

    while(pos < length) {
        for(i = 0; i < numOfChan; i++) {             // interleave channels
            sample = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, channels[i][offset])); // clamp
            sample = (0.5 + sample < 0 ? sample * 32768 : sample * 32767)|0; // scale to 16-bit signed int
            view.setInt16(pos, sample, true);          // update data chunk
            pos += 2;
        }
        offset++                                     // next source sample
    }

    // create Blob
    return new Blob([buffer], {type: "audio/mpeg"});

    function setUint16(data) {
        view.setUint16(pos, data, true);
        pos += 2;
    }

    function setUint32(data) {
        view.setUint32(pos, data, true);
        pos += 4;
    }
}
```

you can look into it.
https://github.com/vikasmagar512/wavesurfer-audio-editor

Answer (score -1):

use

```
this.wavesurfer.on("region-update-end", reg => {
//this will allow you to see the start date correctly, 
//even if you dragged the region it will display right.
    console.log(reg.start)
    
  });
```

This works only when the region-created function finishes it's work, so it has filled up all variables and now you can access them easily.